# How to prove $a_1^2+\ldots +a_n^2\ge \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$.  Then how to prove $$ \sum_{i=1}^na_i\ge 1\implies \sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\ge\frac{1}{n}. $$

I tried induction but did not get it. Please help.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a nice geometric heuristics about this issue, that I give for $n=2$,  extensible in a straightforward way to any $n$.

$x+y \geq 1$ defines a half plane (a halfspace for a general $n$).

$x^2+y^2 \geq \dfrac12$ is represented by the exterior of the origin-centered disk with radius $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ (general version : by the exterior of the hypersphere with radius $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.)

Implication: $x+y \geq 1 \implies x^2+y^2 \geq \dfrac12$ is "rendered convincingly" by the inclusion of the first region (in blue in the graphics below) into the second region.

Let us repeat that it is an heuristic method, which does not replace a rigorous proof.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the Power Mean Inequality. You will obtain:

$$\sqrt{\frac{\sum a_i^2}{n}} =\sqrt{\frac{\sum |a_i^2|}{n}} \ge \frac{\sum |a_i|}{n} \ge \frac{\sum a_i}{n} \iff \sum a_i^2 \ge n \cdot \frac{\left(\sum a_i\right)^2}{n^2} = \frac 1n$$

Comment: Don't $a_i$ have to be nonnegative for the power mean inequality?

Comment: @mechanodroid Yeah, but you can easily take care of it by taking absolute value. Anyway thanks for noticing I will fix the answer

Answer (score 3):

Assume that the claim is false.  Then use Cauchy -Schwarz to get  a contradiction

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz is fine for this problem, but no need for a proof by contradiction. A direct proof works just as easily.